# Segmentation fault in NASM X86

Tags: x86, segmentation-fault, nasm, game-development

```
assembly
section .data
    playerLives: dd 5
    gameOver: dd 0
    timesReset: dd 0
    playerY: dd 5
    playerX: dd 5
    playerScore: dd 0

   section .text
   global _start
   global _completeReset
   global _resetGame
   global _resetCMP
   global _checkPlayerScore

   _start:
    cmp dword [gameOver], 1
    je _resetCMP

_resetCMP:
    add dword [timesReset], 1
    cmp dword [timesReset], 4
    je _completeReset
    jl _reset

_completeReset:
    mov dword [playerLives], 10
    mov dword [gameOver], 0
    mov dword [timesReset], 0
    mov dword [playerX], 5
    mov dword [playerY], 5
    mov dword [playerScore], 0

_reset:
    mov dword [playerLives], 5
    mov dword [timesReset], 0
    mov dword [playerScore], 0
    mov dword [gameOver], 0
```

This code will reset, completely reset, compare code variables for my game.
It will eventually be the player logic but as you can see I have ran into an error and hope I could get some help.

If so thanks for the help if my question is closed I will go to a different site (don’t need to add that obviously)

Comment: Is this the whole program, with nothing after the line `mov dword [gameOver], 0`?

Comment: Yes, it is………..

Comment: Then it does not exit cleanly, the zero-padding after the last line will be executed (decoded as `add BYTE PTR [eax],al`)

Comment: So, I need to add an exit call

Comment: Yes, is this for Windows or a linux-like OS? The way to exit a program is different between them

Comment: Kali Linux. Thanks

Comment: Then, if you are on x86, you have to exit the following way:
if your code is x86 (32 bits):
`mov eax, 1` (newline) 
`xor ebx, ebx ; exit code` (newline) 
`int 80h`   
if x86-64 (64 bits):
`mov rax, 60` (newline) 
`xor rdi, rdi` (newline) 
`syscall` (sorry for this format, but comments don't support newlines)